# Create glowing text effect on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

We're currently building an iPhone app and would like the text to have a glowing effect to fit in with the realistic UI design.

Here is what we're trying to achieve.

[image: glowing text]

We are struggling to create the inner glow effect at the moment so any help would be appreciated.

In photoshop this text has

- a color of #98c1c1
- Outer glow: #ffffff, Screen blend mode, 30% opacity, 5px size.
- Inner glow: #c79d85, Color Dodge blend mode, 70% opacity, 5px size.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: This possibly can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420131/iphone-text-glow-effect or this http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2010/04/29/create-glow-soft-shadow-text-on-iphone/

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482103/77567) should help you with the inner glow.

Answer (score 14):

To set up the button with the text colored #98c1c1, use:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 60)];
label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)152/255) green:((float) 193/255) blue:((float) 193/255) alpha:1.0f];
```

I used Photoshop to find RGB components of #98c1c1, which ended up being R:152 G:193 B:193. And `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` takes a normalized value between 0 and 1, and that's why I made it the RGB value over 255.

For the outer glow, use:

```
label.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);    
label.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
label.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

You want the opacity to be 30% and the shadow color #ffffff (white). That is why `label.layer.shadowOpacity` is set to 0.3 (30%) and `label.layer.shadowColor` is set to white.

I'm not quite sure about how to implement the inner glow, but you could possibly create a method that duplicates the text but makes the font smaller and centers the new text, to create the effect of an inner glow. Remember to import `<Quartzcore/Quartzcore.h>`!

Answer (score -1):

Updating the code [posted by pasawaya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253941):

```
label.layer.shadowColor = ([UIColor .green] as! CGColor)
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
label.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.
label.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: Can you also [edit] the answer to explain *why* this change is necessary?